# Spring, Atomikos, Tibco EMS 5.1 integration issue

Tags: spring, configuration, atomikos, tibco-ems

I am trying to configure [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/) in my Spring application. I am using:

- Atomikos 3.7.1 (TransactionsEssentials)
- Spring 3.0.2
- Tibco EMS 5.1

Can some one give me the configuration details for the connection factory using JNDI for JMS and also details regarding Tibco EMS configuration?

I had tried the following:

```
 <bean id="jmsTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" >
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="queue" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="messageConverter"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean"    init-method="init">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="XAEMS" />
    <property name="xaConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="emsConnectionFactory">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup> 

<jee:jndi-lookup id="queue" jndi-name="emsQueue">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

But get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in file [C:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.4.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\iRebal-Backend-Poc-Web-Integration-Final-xa\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\batch\jobs\priority-queue.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory' for property 'xaConnectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory] for property 'xaConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory' for property 'xaConnectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory] for property 'xaConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is too late for the OP, but for the sake of posterity:

The class you want is com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsXAConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in class `com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean` you have a field named `xaConnectionFactory` that its type (or its getter return type) is `javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory`. However, in Spring configuration file, you configured that field to be set with an instance of which type is `com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory`.

Apparently `com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory` is not convertible to `javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Thats right. I want to know whether tibco has a connectionFactory class that implements javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory interface. I have been able to test it with ActiveMQ successfully.